# How to delete all directories except "default directory" in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

There are lots of questions regarding the deletion of directories but I could not find the one I need! So posting it here.
I have a "pay and go subscription" and I get a default directory. While I was trying out few things in Azure for my learning purposes, I had created few directories. Now I have deleted everything in those directories and they are empty. I want to just keep my default directory and remove all others. But I don't find an option to remove those directories. When I click on switch directory, I find all those redundant directories. Please tell me how to clean up those directories?

Thanks in Advance
Murthy

Comment: Have you checked the steps here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-delete-howto You can switch to the directory you want to delete, go to Azure Active Directory, and then there should be an option to delete that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your admin account to log into Azure AD and switch to the tenant which you want to delete.

[image]

Follow the steps of [Delete the directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-delete-howto#delete-the-directory).

If you have deleted all the resources listed, you can delete it easily.

If you can't delete it, refer to [If you can't delete the directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-delete-howto#if-you-cant-delete-the-directory).